# HTTP Transfer-Encoding "gzip, chunked" not interpreted correctly

Tags: java, http, encoding

I am currently implementing an HTTP server in Java but faced one problem when it comes to transfer encoding.

While

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

works properly, using `gzip` and `chunked` as transfer encoding only like this:

```
Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked
```

results in the browser not displaying the response correctly.

While Chrome tries downloading the resource as a `.gz` file, Firefox tries to display it which results in this:

[image: Expected output: Hello world!]

The strange thing about this is that the message body generated by the server is exactly the same as when using `gzip` as `Content-Encoding` instead, because RFC7230 allows to apply multiple transfer encodings if the last one applied is `chunked`.

> For example,
>
> ```
> Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked
> ```
>
> indicates that the payload body has been compressed using the gzip
>     coding and then chunked using the chunked coding while forming the
>     message body.

This is the original response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 17:52:41 GMT
Server: jPuzzle
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked

1c
       òHÍÉÉW(Ï/ÊIQ   ÿÿ
a
    
0
```

As one can guess, the body is gziped and chunked after that.

I would appreciate any help because I can't see where the specs have been violated.

Comment: Headers might be correct but transferred data might not be in gzip format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul use `content-encoding` header for [end to end compression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding).

> Transfer-Encoding is a hop-by-hop header, that is applied to a message between two nodes, not to a resource itself. Each segment of a multi-node connection can use different Transfer-Encoding values. If you want to compress data over the whole connection, use the end-to-end Content-Encoding header instead.

Also, send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header to tell the server what the client expects.

Comment: Well, I thought that it does not matter in which field to put `gzip` as it is listed as a registered transfer encoding here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml
But do the specs say it is not allowed to compress using transfer encoding?

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding` is for node to node encoding, you need end to end one.